# what causes this error 'Unable to write to application file.ini'

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

My application is build in delphi and it runs perfect on other platforms except Windows 7 64bit machine. Each and everytime try to close the application is giving me this error
'Unable to write to application file.ini'

here is my code for closing

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
      frmMain.close;
end;
```

Comment: This code is wrong,  BTW. Remove `frmMain`, and just use `Close`. Adding `frmMain` ties it to a single instance of the form instead of working on any instance. If you **must** qualify it for some reason,  use `Self` instead of a specific variable name.

Comment: Its wrong to call `Close()` from inside the `OnClose` event handler at all, as `Close()` is already running so this creates an endlesss recursive loop.

Answer (score 10):

This error is usually caused by trying to write to your app's own folder under `Program Files`, which is not allowed for a non-Administrator under Vista and higher (and XP, if you're not running as an Administrator or Power User).

Here's some code for getting the proper folder for your .INI file:

```
uses
  Windows,
  ShlObj;   // For SHGetSpecialFolderPath

function GetFolderLocation(Handle: HWnd; Folder: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := '';
  SetLength(Result, MAX_PATH);
  if not SHGetSpecialFolderPath(Handle, PChar(Result), Folder, False) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

I use these in my application to retrieve the non-roaming profile folder, and use a sub-folder created beneath that for my app's data. It's set up during the creation of a `TDataModule`:

```
procedure TAppData.Create(Sender.TObject);
begin
  // DataPath is a property of the datamodule, declared as a string
  // CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA is the local non-roaming profile folder.
  // CSIDL_APPDATA is for the local roaming profile folder, and is more typically used
  DataPath := GetFolderLocation(Application.Handle, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA);
  DataPath := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(DataPath) + 'MyApp\';
end;
```

See [MSDN's documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the meaning of the various `CSIDL_` or `FOLDERID_` values. The `FOLDERID_` values are similar, but are available only on Vista and above and used with [SHGetKnownFolderIDList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For those of you **not** willing to disregard MS's warnings about `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` not being supported, here's an alternate version of `GetFolderLocation` using `SHGetFolderPath`, which is preferred:

```
uses
  ShlObj, SHFolder, ActiveX, Windows;

function GetFolderLocation(Handle: HWnd; Folder: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := '';
  SetLength(Result, MAX_PATH);
  if not Succeeded(SHGetFolderPath(Handle, Folder, 0, 0, PChar(Result))) then
      RaiseLastOSError();
end;
```

And finally, for those working with only Vista and higher, here's an example using [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - note this isn't available in pre-XE versions of Delphi (AFAIK-may be in 2009 or 2010), and you'll need to use [KNOWNFOLDERID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) values instead of `CSIDL_`, like `FOLDERID_LocalAppData`:

```
uses
  ShlObj, ActiveX, KnownFolders;

// Tested on XE2, VCL forms application, Win32 target, on Win7 64-bit Pro
function GetFolderLocation(const Folder: TGuid): string;
var
  Buf: PWideChar;
begin
  Result := '';
  if Succeeded(SHGetKnownFolderPath(Folder, 0, 0, Buf)) then
  begin
    Result := Buf;
    CoTaskMemFree(Buf);
  end
  else
    RaiseLastOSError();
end;
```

Comment: It would be very unusual to use `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA` since that is non-roaming. Use `CSIDL_APPDATA` instead. Also it is **far** easier to call `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` instead and avoid the PIDL dance, if you are prepared to ignore the dire MS warnings that `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` is unsupported!

Comment: @David, good catch. Pre-`RaiseLastOSError` versions of Delphi did it with `SysErrorMessage` instead, and the old code snippet lib still had that in it (along with some other old stuff, as you saw). It's been updated now. :-)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA` if you don't need to support roaming. And `SHGetSpecialFolderPath()` is not supported by MS anymore, use `SHGetFolderPath()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You should not write ini files to the program directory. Although it *worked* in the past, it has never been a good practice.

You should be using `%APPDATA%` for user specific application data.

You might want to read [Best practices storing application data](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/77aaf6e1-8de5-4529-9b26-fa89b55fcc49)