# Why is COMMON_APPDATA returned as a null string on Windows XP

Tags: delphi, winapi

One of my users at a large university (with, I imagine, the aggressive security settings that university IT departments general have on their computers) is getting an *empty string* returned by Windows XP for CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA or CSIDL_PERSONAL.  (I'm not sure which of these is returning the empty string, because I haven't yet examined his computer to see how he's installed the software, but I'm pretty sure it's the COMMON_APPDATA...)

Has anyone encountered this or have suggestions on how to deal with this?

Here's the Delphi code I'm using to retrieve the value:

```
Function GetSpecialFolder( FolderID: Integer):String;
var
  PIDL: PItemIDList;
  Path: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(Application.Handle, FolderID, PIDL);
  SHGetPathFromIDList(PIDL, Path);
  Result := Path;
end;  { GetSpecialFolder }

ShowMessage(GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA));  <--- This is an empty string
```

Edit:

Figuring out this API made me feel like I was chasing my tail - I went in circles trying to find the right call. This method and others similar to it are said to be deprecated by Microsoft (as well as by a earlier poster to this question (@TLama?) who subsequently deleted the post.) But, it seems like most of us, including me, regularly and safely ignore that status.

In my searches, I found a good answer here on SO from some time ago, including sample code for the *non*-deprecated way of doing this: [what causes this error 'Unable to write to application file.ini'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222132/what-causes-this-error-unable-to-write-to-application-file-ini).

Comment: SHGetSpecialFolderLocation and SHGetPathFromIDList are both functions, and the call may fail, but you're ignoring the function result, in order to gather more info about the problem, you shall check the return value of each function and learn who and why are failing.

Comment: You may replace those two functions by a single call of the [`SHGetSpecialFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The note about the leaking `ITEMIDLIST` got lost when @TLama deleted his answer. Use `CoTaskMemFree` or shell's `IMalloc` memory manager to free the IDList.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to find out why an API call is failing you need to check the return values. That's what is missing in this code.

You need to treat each function on its own merits. Read the documentation on MSDN. In the case of `SHGetSpecialFolderLocation`, the return value is an `HRESULT`. For `SHGetPathFromIDList` you get back a `BOOL`. If that is `FALSE` then the call failed.

The likely culprit here is `SHGetSpecialFolderLocation`, the code that receives the CSIDL, but you must check for errors whenever you call Windows API functions.

Taking a look at the documentation for [`CSIDL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb762494.aspx) we see this:

> **CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA**
>
> *Version 5.0*. The file system directory that contains application data for all users. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\All
>   Users\Application Data. This folder is used for application data that
>   is not user specific. For example, an application can store a
>   spell-check dictionary, a database of clip art, or a log file in the
>   CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA folder. This information will not roam and is
>   available to anyone using the computer.

If the machine has a shell version lower than 5.0, then this `CSIDL` value is not supported. That's the only documented failure mode for this `CSIDL` value. I don't think that applies to your situation, so you'll just have to see what the `HRESULT` status code has to say.

Comment: But version 5.0 is Windows 2000/ME, so it should be very unlikely to fail because of a too low shell version...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes. But that is the only failure mode documented.